# Rails inverse polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphism, polymorphic-associations

I'm familiar with using rails' polymorphic associations, where a model can be declared polymorphic to gain the capability of belonging to a multitude of other models, such as:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :commentable, :polymorphic => true
end

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, :as => :commentable
end

class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, :as => :commentable
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, :as => :commentable
end
```

Is there a common pattern to deal with the inverse case, where a model can have a multitude of other models that will be accessed through the same interface (e.g. a person has many pets, where pets can be either dogs, cats, etc.)? Should I just create a virtual attribute?

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? I'm looking to have a similar thing. Although, STI may work for your pet example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your pets example, [STI](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#class-ActiveRecord%3a%3aBase-label-Single+table+inheritance) may be a solution:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pets
end

class Pet < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner, class_name: "Person", foreign_key: "person_id"
  # Be sure to include a :type attribute for STI to work
end

class Dog < Pet
end

class Cat < Pet
end
```

This should still give you access to `@person.pets` and `@dog.owner`, `@pet.owner`, etc.